# Is this a secure enough method to recover data?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, hbs

**I'd love to know if this method I'm using is secure enough to use on a public project, since I can't really find any other way to retrieve my id from my currently logged in user, but it's a fairly straightforward method , I find. If this method is not secure would it be possible to have a way to proceed? Thanks in advance.**

**I have a button for example when I use the send of the html that there is inside my div userid on the server to then use this information to make SQL queries from my app.js server.**

*I use socket.io hbs express node js jwt mysql*

From my pages.js file generated with the express library where the main roads of my website are located, I send my user ID.

```
router.get('/accueil', authController.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    if(req.user) {
        res.render('./accueil', {
            data: req.user.id
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

With Handlebars I display this data in my index.hbs (display: none;).

```
<div id="iduser">{{data}}</div>
```

Then I get my iduser div on my client.js

```
let userid = document.getElementById('iduser').innerHTML;
```

// (My method to display this div)

```
socket.on('uid', (data) => {
    pargent.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data.data[0].argent);
})
```

//

So I want to use this userid variable to make SQL queries from my app.js.
(let userid = document.getElementById('iduser').innerHTML;)

***I am using socket.io for communication between client and server to send my userid data***

Example :

```
db.query('UPDATE users SET money = money + ? WHERE id = ?', [100, theUserId]);
```

Comment: "*I am using socket.io for communication between client and server to send my userid data*" so, if I were to go on your site and push *my* userId through the socket to the server, do I get 100 money? In other words, why in the name of Mitnick are you *trusting user supplied data* which is *the number one thing all security experts and any decent introductions to security are warning against*?

Comment: I have a button for example when I use the send of the html that there is inside my div userid on the server to then use this information to make SQL queries from my app.js server.

Comment: F12 -> Navigate to the hidden div -> change the value -> press the button. I now have 100 money. Or whatever. If the number value also comes from the frontend, then I can set it to -100 and then change the user ID to yours. Then press the button. And *that* is just what a slightly Internet savvy person can do. I can also just connect to your websocket and push any values I wish. Or take over the connection on your site, just in case there is authentication, *then* push any data I want.

Comment: I already tried that to find out but it didn't change my id on the server side. I am using javascriptwebtoken

Answer (score 1):

## No

Never trust user supplied data.

References:

- https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/http-developers-handbook/0672324547/0672324547_ch22lev1sec1.html
- https://flylib.com/books/en/1.290.1.90/1/
- https://www.garybell.co.uk/never-trust-user-input/
- https://medium.com/@berniedurfee/never-trust-a-client-not-even-your-own-2de342723674
- https://www.invicti.com/blog/web-security/input-validation-errors-root-of-all-evil/
- https://laravel-news.com/never-trust-your-users
- https://www.wearenova.co.uk/nova-blog/when-it-comes-to-online-security-why-you-should-never-trust-a-client

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your `authController.isLoggedIn` logic,
But I would like to suggest an alternative solution simple as that;

#### [iron-session](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session)

Read their docs, it's matches your use case and easy to use; here is equivalent of the snippet you provided with iron session:

```
//initiate session middleware yourself
router.use(session)

// later here
router.get('/accueil', (req, res) => {
    if(req.session.user) {
        res.render('./accueil', {
            data: req.user.id
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Comment: I can send my auth.isLoggedIn if needed, but I'll look for iron-session it looks interesting.